# clarification in the proof of spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

So the spectral theorem says that : 
 A symmetric matrix $A \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n} :\mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$ can be written as $M= VDV^T$.

Here is my attempt to prove this:

Assume that there is a eigenvalue $\lambda$ for A with unit eigenvector $v \in \mathcal{V}$. the subspace $U\subset \mathcal{V}$ orthogonal to $v$ is invariante under $A$. So let $\{u_1,..,u_{n-1}\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $U$, and consider matrix $M=[v,u_1,...,u_{n-1}]$ where $v$ and $u_i's$ are column vectors in $M$. Then AM= MB.

Where $B=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\lambda & 0...0 \\
\hline
0's & S
\end{array}
\right]$

$S$ is symmetric because $A=MBM^T$ and $A$ is symmetric. We apply induction on $B$ and diagonalize $B$. Then I'm not sure how to connect the diagonalized form of B to form a diagonalized form for $A$.

Comment: The  statement confuses a matrix with a lnear transformation. Is A a matrix or a linear transformation? How are A and M related? What is V? What is D? Please state EXACTLY  what your version of the spectral theorem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $S=WEW^T$, with $W$ orthogonal and $E$ diagonal. Then 
$$
A=MBM^T=M\begin{bmatrix} \lambda &0\\ 0& WEW^T\end{bmatrix} M^T=M\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&W\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda&0\\0&E\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&W\end{bmatrix} ^TM^T
$$